# jQuery Validate not working with Ajax and jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-ui-dialog

On my website I have a navigation and a main content area. When you click on a navigation link, the content inside the main content area always gets loaded via ajax. If you click the link "Contact", a text gets loaded which contains a link for a jQuery dialog which contains the contact form.

The problem: When you load the website and navigate to the contact form area, the validation works perfectly fine. However, if you navgiate away to another content area (= another content gets loaded via ajax) and then go back to the contact form area and click the submit button (WITHOUT reloading the page in between), validation fails, gets ignored and the form action gets executed. If you reload the page and then navigate to the contact form area, everything works again.

I cannot make sense of this behaviour. What is weird: Validating another form in the content area which is NOT opened in a jQuery dialog always works, no matter what you had clicked before. So it must be because of the jQuery dialog popup and Ajax. Who can make sense of this problem?

Here comes my code:

HTML:

```
<a href="#popup-form-test" id="open-popup-form-test">open form test popup</a>

<div id="popup-form-test">
    <form id="form-test" action="somelink">
        <input type="text" placeholder="testtext eingeben" name="testText"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var dialogTest = $("#popup-form-test").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        close: function () {
            console.log('closed');
        }
    });

    $("#open-popup-form-test").on("click", function () {
        dialogTest.dialog("open");
    });

    $('#form-test').validate({
       debug: true,
        rules : {
            testText: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('submitted');
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's probably because the form is not present in the DOM when you attempt to bind the `.validate()` method to it, therefore causing validation to fail? One possible way around it is not to bind the method at runtime, but only when the form is loaded via AJAX.

Comment: how can i get around this?

Comment: Without a proof-of-concept example (minimal, concrete and verifiable example), it's next to impossible to troubleshoot. You can create an example using JSFiddle or the code snippet here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the [open](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) callback of .dialog() and insert there the validator:

```
var dialogTest = $("#popup-form-test").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    open : function (event, ui) {
      $('#form-test').validate({
        debug: true,
        rules : {
          testText: {
            required: true
          }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
           alert('submitted');
        }
      });
    },
    close: function () {
        console.log('closed');
    }
});
```

i can't test without a valid example but it should work.

Comment: I moved my validation code into the dialogTest variable as you suggested, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: you should create a snippet or give a link to the page with the problem.
Actually the callback should be the right way, probably there is something else that block it.